# Spring security can't initialize context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am going through the official spring documentation examples:

adding spring security to application without it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html

creating custom login
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

and have successfully added security to my application. However, when I go to add a custom login the documentation talks about a dependency "since our project adds the messages-jc project as a dependency..." so I added this to my pom. Since I have added this it throws an error as shown below.

I can remove this error if I exclude my SecurityWebApplicationInitializer and then run the app, however the system does not correctly redirect to the login page, and the login page does not work correctly (I use th:if and none of the if statements work it acts as if all of the if statements are true even if I say th:if="false"). If I remove the jc-messages dependency then it redirects correctly however the login page still does not work and trying to login throws a `invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN` error.

It seems as if the security class is being registered more than once triggering the error, but when I take away the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer nothing is registering the class. I feel like there is something basic I am missing since I am following a simple tutorial however I can't figure out what it is. The only other thing I could think of besides being a spring problem is that there is something wrong with Thymeleaf which is keeping the login page from not working.

Any help is appreciated!

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml** Commented out other dependencies to isolate the springframework dependency problem

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- ... other dependency elements ... -->
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-samples-messages-jc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/res/**").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
            .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/loginSpring.html")
              .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**loginSpring.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title tiles:fragment="title">Messages : Create</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div tiles:fragment="content">
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">               
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Login</legend>
                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
                    Invalid username and password.
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
                    You have been logged out.
                </div>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>        
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jul 23, 2014 5:47:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 23, 2014 5:47:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/geocounts] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 23, 2014 5:47:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet dispatcher threw unload() exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.destroy() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1723)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5427)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.destroy(FrameworkServlet.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1377)
    ... 24 more
```

**Broken login page**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using Java based configuration for Spring Security, [CSRF protection is enabled by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure).  You can switch it off as `http.csrf().disable()`.

Comment: This allows the login to go through however it does not fix the larger overall problem. The formatting and if statements on loginSpring don't work at all.